# How to use more than 2 redis nodes in django celery

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery

Celery currently has parameters for a broker and backend.  Am I able to add even more nodes?

I have 5 nodes.  How would I reference them in the configuration celeryapp.py

```
app = Celery('mytaks',
                 broker='redis://clusternode1/0',
                 backend='redis://clusternode1/0',
                 include=['tasks',]
                 )
```

Comment: Celery doesn't have support for using Redis cluster as broker. It can use Redis highly available setup as broker (with Sentinels), but has no support for Redis cluster to be used as broker.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar What about just using 3 nodes, not a cluster?

Comment: you may not add different Redis nodes as brokers to the  Celery. Only way to do that is through Sentinels where Sentinels take care of sending the writes to current Redis master and also transparently fails over to new master if the current master goes down.  http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html